# kubernetes create cinder pvc on Openstack Failed with error message: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters

Tags: kubernetes, cinder

[root@vm-10-75-145-71 ~]# kubectl describe pvc datadir-belk-efkc-belk-elasticsearch-data-1 -nheema

```
Name:          datadir-belk-efkc-belk-elasticsearch-data-1
Namespace:     heema
StorageClass:  cinder-az-nova
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        component=elasticsearch
               release=belk-efkc
               role=data
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner=kubernetes.io/cinder
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                  From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                 ----                         -------

>Warning  ProvisioningFailed  4m (x3261 over 13h)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "cinder-az-nova": failed to create a 50 GB volume: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.
```

yml file is like this:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pvc001
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: cinder-az-nova
```

This yml file will create an pending pvc with the same Exception.

Comment: can you show your yaml/json config for this? also show the output of `$ kubectl get storageclass`

Comment: I can get the "cinder-az-nova" from $kubectl get sc,

Answer (score 0):

It might be a completely different reason but try checking your "availability" parameter. Through a kubespray installation you will get a default storage template that uses availability=nova. Your openstack provider might name the zones differently. In my case the zones were "eu-de-01/2"